# Gio::OutputStream to a String or std::ostream

Tags: c++, glib, gtkmm

I am using the library libvtemm, which has a function `write_contents`.  It takes an internal buffer and outputs it to a `Glib::RefPtr<Gio::OutputStream>` object.  I have been trying to find a way to convert the contents of the Gio::OutputStream into a `std::string` or something similar so that I can play with and move around the data inside to other data structures.

Does anyone know how to either construct a `Gio::OutputStream` to something like a `std::ostream` or convert its contents into a `std::string`?

I see there is a `Gio::MemoryOutputStream`, would something like this be useful in grabbing the data to a `std::ostream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are looking for an answer, here is what I have come up with to read the console buffer into a `std::string`.

```
// Create a mock stream just for this example
Glib::RefPtr<Gio::MemoryOutputStream> bufStream =
  Gio::MemoryOutputStream::create(NULL, 0, &realloc, &free);

// Create the stringstream to use as an ostream
std::stringstream ss;

// Get the stream size so we know how much to allocate
gsize streamSize = bufStream->get_data_size();
char *charBuf = new char[streamSize+1];

// Copy over the data from the buffer to the charBuf
memcpy(charBuf, bufStream->get_data(), streamSize);

// Add the null terminator to the "string"
charBuf[streamSize] = '\0';

// Create a string from it
ss << charBuf;
```

Hope this helps someone in the future who comes across a similar problem.